# Why I had to change my tmux vim regexp recognition?

Tags: vim, tmux

As many people, I have several lines of tmux config copied from somewhere else. One of them is the "detect if is VIM window" one. No matter ho much I find, I always find the same set of lines and regex.
Suddenly, one day, tmux stopped recognising that I was on a vim window and was not sending the proper keystrokes to the program. It took me a lot to debug, I even had to add tty information to my tmux panes in order to be able to run the commands manually.

After some pain, I found that the original regex was no longer matching the right outputs, so I modified it:

It was like this before

```
is_vim="ps -o state= -o comm= -t '#{pane_tty}' \
    | grep -iqE '^[^TXZ ]+ +(\\S+\\/)?g?(view|n?vim?x?)(diff)?$'"
```

And I had to change to this

```
is_vim="ps -o state= -o comm= -t '#{pane_tty}' \
    | grep -iqE '(\\S+\\/)?g?(view|n?vim?x?)(diff)?$'"
```

As you can see, I removed `^[^TXZ ]+ +`. Since my command output no longer matches that, I had no idea what was it for, and specially, why it changed from one day to the next.
I will love to understand what that was trying to match, and why it may have changed.

For reference, here is the new output I get when I execute the said command in a normal terminal

```
Ss   -zsh
S    -zsh
S    -zsh
S    -zsh
S    /Users/danielo/.cache/gitstatus/gitstatusd-darwin-arm64
S+   lvim
```

Why this may have changed, and what was the output before is still a mystery to me

Regards

Comment: That is how I knew the regex was no longer valid. But the question is why something like that may change. Gonna update the question with the info nayway

Comment: Indeed, I use lvim, and the previous regex was working before. Note that the regex I'm using now does not account for lvim either, and still it works. the first character is ignored. I just removed the `TXZ` thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're using `lvim` now, not `vim`.

> ```
> grep -iqE '^[^TXZ ]+ +(\\S+\\/)?g?(view|n?vim?x?)(diff)?$'
> ```

(that `\\` likely a mistake)

Matches on lines from the output of `ps` that

- start (`^`) with one-or-more (`+`) characters other than `T`, `X`, `Z` and space, followed by
- one or more spaces followed by
- an optional sequence of non-whitespaces ending in `/` followed by
- an optional `g`, either `view` or `vi` optionally preceded by `n` and followed by `m` and/or `x`, followed by an optional `diff` followed by
- the end of the line (`$`).

So it matches on `S+  gviewdiff` for instance or `YY /path/to/vi`, but not `Z vim` (suspended `vim`), not `YY lvim` (not `YY /vim` either btw).

> ```
> grep -iqE '(\\S+\\/)?g?(view|n?vim?x?)(diff)?$'
> ```

Matches anywhere in the line (no `^` anchor to the start of the line) some optional sequence of one or more characters ending in `/` and those alternative spellings of `vim` and their variants like above.

Since the regexp is not anchored at the start the `(\\S+\\/)?g?` and `n?` are redundant, it would match the same lines with or without it, so it's the same as:

```
grep -iqE 'vi(ew|m?x?)(diff)?$'
```

So it does match on `ZZ whatever lvimdiff` because it matches `vimdiff` within it.

To allow `lvim` while still checking the state of the process, you'd want something like:

```
is_vim="ps -o state= -o comm= -t '#{pane_tty}' \
    | grep -ixqE '[^TXZ ]+ +(\\S*/)?[gl]?(view|n?vim?x?)(diff)?'"
```

(using the `-x` option so as not to have to specify the `^` and `$` anchors, and replacing `\\S+` with `\\S*` to allow `/vi`. You could change to `.*` to also allow `Ss /my cool apps/vi`.

Comment: This is the only explanation that I found about how and why works in the whole internet. Thank you very much.